# Migrate a project from mootools to prime

Tags: javascript, class, mootools

I should use prime or primish?

What should I do to use primish in the browser?

Any examples available?

Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: Voted re-open since this is Mootools related and relevant.

Answer (score 4):

as the author/co-maintainer of `primish`, I can clear a few differences at least.

`prime` is a collective of micro js frameworks and utils, like `agent`, `elements`, `moo.fx`, `prime` itself - though strictly speaking, the former do not belong in `prime` and do not yet depend on it. if used as intended as such a set, it is more of a complete solution you can usilise in a small to medium type of project, a lot more akin to `mootools` is. prime has been written in `common js` (CJS) under node and wraps for browser via a build step right now, either as AMD or exports to global. it has the backing of the `mootools-core`, mostly written by Valerio himself with help from Arian and Kentaromuira, amongst others. currently under continued and still changing a lot (eg, 2 weeks ago deprecated shell/utils/array etc and picked `mout` and not `lodash` - see https://github.com/mootools/prime/tree/mout, read comments https://github.com/mootools/prime/commit/19cb871bc47d1dca1a14ebd06c1b713ca34b7ea8).

primish is a web ready (or nodejs) implementation of the class constructor sugar of prime that has been modified to work more like the Class of mootools itself. it supports things like supers (parent) or options or emitter mixins. it also does things like event pseudos etc once again in the style of mootools.

primish is web ready. it's packaged to work under either cjs, AMD (requirejs, almond etcetera) or globals via a UMD wrapper. it is also on bower so you can just do `bower install primish --save` out of the box.

it allows OOP but does nothing else like array, string, function or object utils. no dom engine either and no animation. you can use lodash jquery etc, whatever you like. I wrote primish because I was forced to abandon mootools work and wanted Class. currently used extensively in a few projects (inc banks) on top of jquery or angularjs.

should you update? well. it's up to you. if there is a call for change of stack you may consider it but depends on your goals, I cannot give you objective advice over it.

to get an idea about what's involved, here is a project I am migrating at the moment.

compare model via primish and lodash:

- https://github.com/DimitarChristoff/epik/blob/master/lib/model.js

...with model via mootools:

- https://github.com/epitome-mvc/Epitome/blob/master/src/epitome-model.js

not very different and the new model has a nearly 100% identical api - cept for the `extend` and `implement` keywords (although design changes may dictate other differences).

end user usage under primish:

- https://github.com/DimitarChristoff/epik/blob/master/dist/example/js/model.js

keep in mind these links are subject to change as I am currently writing epik quite actively and it's pre-release.